# Table with sort using column Headers in UI5. Table sorter

Tags: sapui5

I would like to provide table sorter i.e possibility to sort the table by clicking on a Column. For Example: Product Name column shows the possibility to sort. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview

I want to do a similar thing in sap.m.table as I see sap.ui.table is not valid for phones according to https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.table.Table/overview

Can I achieve this in some way? Or any insights on any alternative approach I can take?

Comment: Here is an example of view settings for m.Table https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.m.sample.TableViewSettingsDialog/preview

Comment: Hi Andri, I am aware of table settings and do not want my sorting to be handled there. I am looking at column based sorting in particular.

Comment: If you plan to use it on mobile devices - this is not a good idea. Because when the columns are not fit to the screen width, they will go in a pop-in area and all the concept of column-clicking-sorting will be failed. Because column name will be shown per each table row, which is confusing. I would recommend to stay with fiori guidelines.